# Python's PEP 484 type annotation for Generator Expression

Tags: python, generator, yield, type-hinting

What is the correct type annotation for a function that returns a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)?

e.g.:

```
def foo():
    return (x*x for x in range(10))
```

I can't figure out if this is `-> Iterator[int]`, `-> Iterable[int]`, `-> Generator[int, None, None]`, or something else.

If *there should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it*, then what is the *obvious way* here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quick note: your function is a "regular function which returns a generator", not a "generator function". To understand the distinction, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44646231/5492820).

For your `foo`, I suggest using `-> Iterator[int]`.

## Explanation

It boils down to what kind of interface you want.

First, make yourself familiar with [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) in the python documentation where the hierarchy of the most important Python types is defined.

You can see there that these expressions return `True`:

```py
import typing as t
issubclass(t.Iterator, t.Iterable)
issubclass(t.Generator, t.Iterator)
```

You should also notice on the same page that `Generator` has methods that `Iterator` doesn't have. These methods are `send`, `throw` and `close` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods)), and they allow you to do more with generators than just simple single passthrough iteration. Check this question for examples of the possibilities with generators: [What is the purpose of the "send" function on Python generators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19302530/5492820)

Going back to choosing an interface. If you want others to use the results of your generator function like a generator, i.e.

```py
def gen(limit: int): -> Generator[int, None, None]
    for x in range(limit):
        yield x

g = gen(3)
next(g)  # => 0
g.send(10)  # => 1
```

Then you should specify `-> Generator[int, None, None]`.

**But notice that above is nonsense.** You in fact can call `send`, but it doesn't change the execution because `gen` doesn't do anything with sent value (there is nothing like `x = yield`).
Knowing that, you can limit the knowledge of people using `gen` and define it as `-> Iterator[int]`. In this way, you can make a contract with users that "my function returns iterator of integers and you should use it as such". If you later change implementation to, e.g.

```py
def gen(limit: int): -> Iterator[int]
    return iter(list(range(limit)))
```

Those who used a returned object like `Generator` (because they peeked implementation) would have their code broken. However, you shouldn't be bothered by that because they used it in a different way to the way specified in your contract. As such, this kind of breakage is not your responsibility.

Put simply, if you end up with `Generator[Something, None, None]` (two `None`s) then consider `Iterable[Something]` or `Iterator[Something]`.

The same goes for `Iterator` vs `Iterable`. If you want your users to be able to use your object only with the `iter` function (and thus be used in iteration context e.g. `[x for x in g]`), then use `Iterable`. If you want them to use both `next` and `iter` on the object, use `Iterator`.

## Note

This line of thought applies mostly to the annotated type of **returned values**. In the case of parameters, you should specify the types according to what interface (read: methods/functions) you want to use on that object inside your function.

Answer (score 25):

All three forms mentioned by you in question are listed as [valid alternatives in documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator), Generator expression simply creates a generator that only yields.

Quote 1:

> A generator can be annotated by the generic type `Generator[YieldType,
>   SendType, ReturnType]`.

Quote 2:

> If your generator will only yield values, set the `SendType` and
>   `ReturnType` to `None`

Quote 3:

> Alternatively, annotate your generator as having a return type of
>   either `Iterable[YieldType]` or `Iterator[YieldType]`:

Comment: I understand the difference for Generator (in cases where you have an SendType and ReturnType), but I don't understand the difference between Iterable and Iterator. Or rather, I don't see how Iterable is correct. Doesn't Iterable imply that you can derive multiple Iterators from it (like List, Set, Tuple)? Whereas a generator, once you consume it once, it's over. So isn't Iterable incorrect?

Comment: @EhsanKia, the formal definitions for `Iterable`/`Iterator`  are in the `collections.abc` module. If you look at the source code, the definition of an `Iterable` is  very broad: it is simply "anything implementing an `__iter__` method". The definition of `Iterator` is "anything implementing  a `__next__` method". If a class implements `__next__`, `__iter__` can be inferred (it doesn't  need to be explicitly defined). So, all iterators are iterables, but not all iterables are iterators. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d3eaf0cc5b311ad023fd13e367f817d528403306/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L253