# PEP 3107 annotation for a generator function

Tags: python, pep

simple question : What is the correct [PEP 3107](https://peps.python.org/pep-3107/) keyword for a function that yields items ?

Already tried this, but it doesn't work

```py
def this_function() -> generator:
    for x in range(0,100):
        yield x
```

Also tried with `Iterator[int]` as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158516/13084358) suggests, but no results. Also tried the various propositions made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227288/pythons-pep-484-type-annotation-for-generator-expression), but nothing

N.B. Don't know if this is relevant, but my linter is Pylance on VSCode

Comment: `Iterator[int]` should have been fine. What error did you get?

Comment: @chepner I get an alert saying `"Iterator" is not defined`

Comment: It's not in the built-in scope; you have to import it from `collections.abc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.abc.Generator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Generator)

```
from collections.abc import Generator

def this_function() -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    for x in range(0, 100):
        yield x
```

Or simply: [`collections.abc.Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterator) or [`collections.abc.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable).

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def this_function() -> Iterable[int]:
    for x in range(0, 100):
        yield x
```

Comment: Note that the documentation also sanctions the use of `Iterator[X]` or `Iterable[X]` in place of `Generator[X, None, None]`.

Comment: (Also, `typing.Generator` is deprecated in favor of `collections.abc.Generator`. `typing` versions of various collections were only needed because the abstract classes weren't generic until Python 3.9.)

Comment: Thank you @chepner I was definitely behind the times.